# How can I non-iteratively place a NaN in a DataFrame column if there is a corresponding NaN in any other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a 3-column DataFrame, `df`:

```
    a    b      c
0 NaN    a   True
1   1    b   True
2   2    c  False
3   3  NaN  False
4   4    e   True

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

I would like to place a`NaN` in column `c` for each row where a `NaN` exists in any other colunn.  My current approach is as follows:

```
for col in df:
    df['c'][pd.np.isnan(df[col])] = pd.np.nan
```

I strongly suspect that there is a way to do this via logical indexing instead of iterating through columns as I am currently doing.

How could this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: So what output column do you want?  Do you need `[NaN, True, False, NaN, True]` or will `[NaN, 1, 0, NaN, 1]` suffice?  And can we assume that `c` will never be NaN before this?

Comment: @DSM, I'd like for column `c` to be preserved *except* for the rows in which another column has a `NaN`.  Thus, I'd expect column `c` to be `[NaN, True, False, NaN, True]`.  Also, yes, we can assume there are initially no NaNs in column `c`.

Comment: @blz I'm not sure that is possible, once you assign `NaN` you get a dtype conversion to `float`s as `bool`s cannot represent `NaN` in any meaningful way.

Comment: @EdChum, That's actually not a problem.  This is just an example -- my actual data has floats in it's equivalent to the `c` column.  Thanks for bringing this up, though!

Comment: @EdChum: you can do it if you use `dtype=object`, but it's not as clean.

Comment: @DSM didn't know that, thanks for letting me know this little tidbit of information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about the bool/float issue, I propose:

```
>>> df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), "c"] = np.nan
>>> df
    a    b   c
0 NaN    a NaN
1   1    b   1
2   2    c   0
3   3  NaN NaN
4   4    e   1

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

If you really do, then starting again from your frame `df` you could:

```
>>> df["c"] = df["c"].astype(object)
>>> df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), "c"] = np.nan
>>> df
    a    b      c
0 NaN    a    NaN
1   1    b   True
2   2    c  False
3   3  NaN    NaN
4   4    e   True

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.c[df.ix[:, :'c'].apply(lambda r: any(r.isnull()), axis=1)] = np.nan
```

Note that you may need to change the type of column `c` to float or you'll get an error about being unable to assign `nan` to integer column.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `DataFrame.apply` to @EdChum's solution using bitwise OR ?

Comment: @blz -- Here you don't need to specify `a` and `b` so it is presumably a little more flexible.

Comment: This solution works no matter how many columns you have, whereas EdChum's requires you to name each column individually.

Comment: @mgilson, ah yes! Good point.  I was just about to ask if he could generalize his answer to work for all columns, regardless of name or number.  This makes BrenBarn's solution very interesting indeed!

Comment: @BrenBarn your answer does not assign `NaN` to `df.c`

Answer (score 2):

filter and select the rows where you have `NaN` for either 'a' or 'b' and assign 'c' to `NaN`:

```
In [18]:

df.ix[pd.isnull(df.a) | pd.isnull(df.b),'c'] = NaN

In [19]:

df

Out[19]:

    a    b   c
0 NaN    a NaN
1   1    b   1
2   2    c   0
3   3    d   0
4   4  NaN NaN

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Brilliant!  That should have been pretty obvious!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @blz no worries, it seems there is an implicit dtype conversion after assigning `NaN`, it converts to float64 probably because `NaN` has no meanings for `bool`s. You would need to take this into account

Comment: @Jeff Yes you are right, we should avoid chain indexing at all costs!! Will update

Comment: @blz it doesn't always work see [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), in 0.13.0 it will warn you and you should avoid this in order to avoid unexpected behaviour